# ASCII-fication of playing cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, playing-cards

I am making a small Blackjack game in Python 3. The part of the code I am unsure about is that which allows me to print nice `ASCII` versions of the card. `ascii_version_of_card()` and `ascii_version_of_hidden_card()`.

**What the program does:**

[image]

---

I am not seeking advice on the implementation of the `Card()` class. Only on `ascii_version_of_card()` and `ascii_version_of_hidden_card()`.

The basic idea of the code is that there are 9 lines of output, and we iterate over all of the card (input) and create the appropriate version of that line for that card. Then we add that line to a master line. In the end we have 9 master lines which are our output.

Since some of the ASCII art is rendered strangely in the browser here is a **[dpaste](http://dpaste.com/1MNZE53)**.

```
class Card(object):

    card_values = {
        'Ace': 11,  # value of the ace is high until it needs to be low
        '2': 2,
        '3': 3,
        '4': 4,
        '5': 5,
        '6': 6,
        '7': 7,
        '8': 8,
        '9': 9,
        '10': 10,
        'Jack': 10,
        'Queen': 10,
        'King': 10
    }

    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        """
        :param suit: The face of the card, e.g. Spade or Diamond
        :param rank: The value of the card, e.g 3 or King
        """
        self.suit = suit.capitalize()
        self.rank = rank
        self.points = self.card_values[rank]

def ascii_version_of_card(*cards, return_string=True):
    """
    Instead of a boring text version of the card we render an ASCII image of the card.
    :param cards: One or more card objects
    :param return_string: By default we return the string version of the card, but the dealer hide the 1st card and we
    keep it as a list so that the dealer can add a hidden card in front of the list
    """
    # we will use this to prints the appropriate icons for each card
    suits_name = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']
    suits_symbols = ['♠', '♦', '♥', '♣']

    # create an empty list of list, each sublist is a line
    lines = [[] for i in range(9)]

    for index, card in enumerate(cards):
        # "King" should be "K" and "10" should still be "10"
        if card.rank == '10':  # ten is the only one who's rank is 2 char long
            rank = card.rank
            space = ''  # if we write "10" on the card that line will be 1 char to long
        else:
            rank = card.rank[0]  # some have a rank of 'King' this changes that to a simple 'K' ("King" doesn't fit)
            space = ' '  # no "10", we use a blank space to will the void
        # get the cards suit in two steps
        suit = suits_name.index(card.suit)
        suit = suits_symbols[suit]

        # add the individual card on a line by line basis
        lines[0].append('┌─────────┐')
        lines[1].append('│{}{}       │'.format(rank, space))  # use two {} one for char, one for space or char
        lines[2].append('│         │')
        lines[3].append('│         │')
        lines[4].append('│    {}    │'.format(suit))
        lines[5].append('│         │')
        lines[6].append('│         │')
        lines[7].append('│       {}{}│'.format(space, rank))
        lines[8].append('└─────────┘')

    result = []
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        result.append(''.join(lines[index]))

    # hidden cards do not use string
    if return_string:
        return '\n'.join(result)
    else:
        return result


def ascii_version_of_hidden_card(*cards):
    """
    Essentially the dealers method of print ascii cards. This method hides the first card, shows it flipped over
    :param cards: A list of card objects, the first will be hidden
    :return: A string, the nice ascii version of cards
    """
    # a flipper over card. # This is a list of lists instead of a list of string becuase appending to a list is better then adding a string
    lines = [['┌─────────┐'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['└─────────┘']]

    # store the non-flipped over card after the one that is flipped over
    cards_except_first = ascii_version_of_card(*cards[1:], return_string=False)
    for index, line in enumerate(cards_except_first):
        lines[index].append(line)

    # make each line into a single list
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        lines[index] = ''.join(line)

    # convert the list into a single string
    return '\n'.join(lines)


# TEST CASES
test_card_1 = Card('Diamonds', '4')
test_card_2 = Card('Clubs', 'Ace')
test_card_3 = Card('Spades', 'Jack')
test_card_4 = Card('Hearts', '10')

print(ascii_version_of_card(test_card_1, test_card_2, test_card_3, test_card_4))
print(ascii_version_of_hidden_card(test_card_1, test_card_2, test_card_3, test_card_4))
# print(ascii_version_of_hidden_card(test_card_1, test_card_2))
```

Comment: Did you consider using `curses`? It would require some changes but it would let you do fancier things like colors and you can let the module handle the rendering. You would just say `draw this box here` and `draw that box there`.

Comment: Looks like something cool here, I like that

Comment: @Holli I did consider using `curses` but decided against it because I wanted it to work in the windows command prompt.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to use curses on windows. You just have to tell the console to expect ANSI codes. See this code, which shows how: https://hastebin.com/ofikovivuw.pl
It's written in Raku/Perl6 but should be easy to port.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nice idea! The printed ASCII cards look great.

---

You could use more list comprehensions.
For example this:

> ```
> result = []
> for index, line in enumerate(lines):
>     result.append(''.join(lines[index]))
> ```

Can be simplified to this:

```
result = [''.join(line) for line in lines]
```

---

Likewise, this:

> ```
> # make each line into a single list
> for index, line in enumerate(lines):
>     lines[index] = ''.join(line)
>
> # convert the list into a single string
> return '\n'.join(lines)
> ```

Can be simplified to this:

```
return '\n'.join([''.join(line) for line in lines])
```

---

In this list comprehension, the variable `i` is unused:

```
lines = [[] for i in range(9)]
```

The common convention is to use the name `_` in such situations (instead of `i`).

---

For better readability,
I recommend to expand this line to multiple lines:

> ```
> lines = [['┌─────────┐'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['│░░░░░░░░░│'], ['└─────────┘']]
> ```

Like this, it's much easier to see that the formatting will be good,
and in any case too long lines are hard to read:

```
lines = [
    ['┌─────────┐'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['│░░░░░░░░░│'],
    ['└─────────┘']
]
```

**Update**

As you pointed out, 7 out of 9 lines there are repeated.
It can be written in a more compact way,
and the function can be further shortened to this:

```
def ascii_version_of_hidden_card(*cards):
    """
    Essentially the dealers method of print ascii cards. This method hides the first card, shows it flipped over
    :param cards: A list of card objects, the first will be hidden
    :return: A string, the nice ascii version of cards
    """
    lines = ['┌─────────┐'] + ['│░░░░░░░░░│'] * 7 + ['└─────────┘']

    cards_except_first = ascii_version_of_card(*cards[1:], return_string=False)

    return '\n'.join([x + y for x, y in zip(lines, cards_except_first)])
```

Comment: Thank you, these are all very good points. But I never did `result = []`, I am not sure where this applies.

Comment: Yes you did, in `ascii_version_of_card` ;-)

Comment: yes, I just found, I feel silly. Do you think that in  your last point `lines` can be further optimized. 7 out of the 9 lines are the same.

Comment: You're right. I thought more about and could compact it even further with less repetition.

Comment: I have never seen this before `return '\n'.join([x + y for x, y in zip(lines, cards_except_first)])` do you mind adding a short comment to the code that explains what it does?

Comment: The `zip` method returns tuples from the 2 list parameters. For example if you have `['a', 'b', 'c']` and `['x', 'y', 'z']`, it will return tuples `('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z')`. The values of the tuples get filled in `x, y` in the expression, and then when you apply `x + y` you get `['ax', 'by', 'cz']`. I hope this clears it up! (See also `help(zip)` in an interactive Python shell)

Answer (score 10):

I know you're not seeking advice about `Card`, but I feel I should point out that you don't need to inherit from `object` in Python 3.

I would remove the `return_string` option; if someone wants a list they should just call `splitlines`.

Your

```
suits_name = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']
suits_symbols = ['♠', '♦', '♥', '♣']
```

should probably be tuples:

```
suits_name = 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs'
suits_symbols = '♠', '♦', '♥', '♣'
```

but they're only ever used as a mapping:

```
name_to_symbol = {
    'Spades':   '♠',
    'Diamonds': '♦',
    'Hearts':   '♥',
    'Clubs':    '♣',
}
```

Your

```
# add the individual card on a line by line basis
lines[0].append('┌─────────┐')
lines[1].append('│{}{}       │'.format(rank, space))  # use two {} one for char, one for space or char
lines[2].append('│         │')
lines[3].append('│         │')
lines[4].append('│    {}    │'.format(suit))
lines[5].append('│         │')
lines[6].append('│         │')
lines[7].append('│       {}{}│'.format(space, rank))
lines[8].append('└─────────┘')
```

looks a bit ugly, but I can see why you did that. What might be better is making an auxillary function to stack lines of strings first:

```
def join_lines(strings):
    string_lines = [string.splitlines() for string in strings]
    return '\n'.join(''.join(out_line) for out_line in zip(*string_lines))
```

And then do:

```
card = (
    '┌─────────┐\n'
    '│{r}{_}       │\n'
    '│         │\n'
    '│         │\n'
    '│    {s}    │\n'
    '│         │\n'
    '│         │\n'
    '│       {_}{r}│\n'
    '└─────────┘\n'
).format(r=rank, _=space, s=suit)

card_strings.append(card)
```

Since the formatting of the card matters for prettiness, I'd be tempted to do:

```
    card = (
        '┌─────────┐\n'
        '│{}       │\n'
        '│         │\n'
        '│         │\n'
        '│    {}   │\n'
        '│         │\n'
        '│         │\n'
        '│       {}│\n'
        '└─────────┘\n'
    ).format(
        format(card.rank, ' <2'),
        format(card.suit, ' <2'),
        format(card.rank, ' >2')
    )
```

Of course, since `card` is from a static, you can move it out to get just

```
    card = CARD.format(
        format(rank, ' <2'),
        format(suit, ' <2'),
        format(rank, ' >2')
    )
```

This removes the need for `space`. You can then make the main loop a comprehension if you make a function, and stick it inside the `join_lines` call:

```
def card_to_string(card):
    # 10 is the only card with a 2-char rank abbreviation
    rank = card.rank if card.rank == '10' else card.rank[0]
    suit = name_to_symbol[card.suit]

    # add the individual card on a line by line basis
    return CARD.format(
        format(rank, ' <2'),
        format(suit, ' <2'),
        format(rank, ' >2')
    )

return join_lines(map(card_to_string, cards))
```

The calls to `format` can be removed by making `card` like:

```
CARD = """\
┌─────────┐
│{}       │
│         │
│         │
│    {}   │
│         │
│         │
│       {}│
└─────────┘
""".format('{rank: <2}', '{suit: <2}', '{rank: >2}')
```

and doing:

```
def card_to_string(card):
    # 10 is the only card with a 2-char rank abbreviation
    rank = card.rank if card.rank == '10' else card.rank[0]

    # add the individual card on a line by line basis
    return CARD.format(rank=rank, suit=name_to_symbol[card.suit])
```

`ascii_version_of_hidden_card` can then be just:

```
def ascii_version_of_hidden_card(*cards):
    """
    Essentially the dealers method of print ascii cards. This method hides the first card, shows it flipped over
    :param cards: A list of card objects, the first will be hidden
    :return: A string, the nice ascii version of cards
    """

    return join_lines((HIDDEN_CARD, ascii_version_of_card(*cards[1:])))
```

Here's the full thing:

```
CARD = """\
┌─────────┐
│{}       │
│         │
│         │
│    {}   │
│         │
│         │
│       {}│
└─────────┘
""".format('{rank: <2}', '{suit: <2}', '{rank: >2}')

HIDDEN_CARD = """\
┌─────────┐
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
│░░░░░░░░░│
└─────────┘
"""

def join_lines(strings):
    """
    Stack strings horizontally.
    This doesn't keep lines aligned unless the preceding lines have the same length.
    :param strings: Strings to stack
    :return: String consisting of the horizontally stacked input
    """
    liness = [string.splitlines() for string in strings]
    return '\n'.join(''.join(lines) for lines in zip(*liness))

def ascii_version_of_card(*cards):
    """
    Instead of a boring text version of the card we render an ASCII image of the card.
    :param cards: One or more card objects
    :return: A string, the nice ascii version of cards
    """

    # we will use this to prints the appropriate icons for each card
    name_to_symbol = {
        'Spades':   '♠',
        'Diamonds': '♦',
        'Hearts':   '♥',
        'Clubs':    '♣',
    }

    def card_to_string(card):
        # 10 is the only card with a 2-char rank abbreviation
        rank = card.rank if card.rank == '10' else card.rank[0]

        # add the individual card on a line by line basis
        return CARD.format(rank=rank, suit=name_to_symbol[card.suit])


    return join_lines(map(card_to_string, cards))


def ascii_version_of_hidden_card(*cards):
    """
    Essentially the dealers method of print ascii cards. This method hides the first card, shows it flipped over
    :param cards: A list of card objects, the first will be hidden
    :return: A string, the nice ascii version of cards
    """

    return join_lines((HIDDEN_CARD, ascii_version_of_card(*cards[1:])))
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer. I feel that doing `splitlines` is a bit redundant because I am just undoing something I just did. It makes more sense not to do it in the first place.

Comment: @Vader That isn't worth worrying about in a routine that prints; it take a few microseconds and you do it at most a few times a second. Even if it was, it's better to have two functions than a parameter that changes the type of the return value - the latter seems likely to cause bugs.